# Можно ли хранить release notes в artifactory?

Tags: java, maven

Правильно ли хранить release notes к бинарям согласно процессу или для этого обычно используют tags и выкладывают сборку тэга ?

Согласно моей задаче необходимо хранить артефакты (не обязательно jar/war/ear) с описанием изменений третьей стороне.